# Sending e-mails to customers on localhost in OpenCart

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am currently working on my development (`localhost`) server, and I am attempting to implement the send e-mail functionality. My hurdle right now is I am unable to setup the SMTP server for OpenCart since I am on localhost.

This is what the setup screen looks like:

[image]

I have checked out articles like this that suggests you to setup a service like [PHPMailer](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/sending-mail-phpmailer.html) for sending an e-mail on localhost, but is there a way to send an e-mail on localhost without adding extraneous code (that won't be used in staging/production) to my dev environment? Perhaps a change in the `mail.php` configurations on OpenCart?

Comment: You can use something like [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/). Note that this is a windows application.there should be similar tools for others as well.

Comment: If you have some SMTP provider (i.e. your e-mail provider) you may set up an SMTP even from your local machine (if it's connected to the internet). I didn't succeeded in installing and using any *mail sending* tools on my Windows PC thus I am using my email provider's SMTP account even from localhost (at least it's working and I am sending mails only for some testing purposes to myself).